# Django - Add 3 users with one form

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to create a form that save 3 users.

#### my forms:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyUsers
        exclude = ('address',)
```

#### my views:

```
def adduser(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        rform = UserForm(request.POST, instance=MyUsers())
        if rform.is_valid():
            new_users = rform.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect...
    else:
        rform = UserForm(instance=MyUsers())
    return render_to_response...
```

#### my template structure:

```
<form method="post">
    {% for field in rform %}
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for field in rform %}
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for field in rform %}
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

#### the problem

The form works properly but add only the last inserted user.

Comment: You should use [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/).

Comment: How can I use formsets? I don't understand the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alasdair's suggestion (formset) is a way to generate multiple instances of the same form at once.
The forms can be rendered in the template by looping over the formset instance:

```
{% for form in formset %}
     {{ form.id }} #PK field is MANDATORY, see reference[2] below
     {{ form.field1 }}
     {{ form.field2 }} #or just as something {{ form.as_p }}
{% endfor %}
```

In your views, formset validation is made once for all `if formset.is_valid():` and `rformset = formset_factory(MyUsers, extra=1, max_num=3)` to create the formset.
Don't forget the imports.

References, both from Django Docs:

[Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/) {1}

[Creating forms from models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) {2}

Comment: Please be specific about your doubt(is it on your template, view, form e.g)

Comment: I don't understand how to integrate it

Comment: If it's too much confusing, create and pass 3 forms instead of just one, like rform1 rform2 and rform3.